# Use "hours" for estimations in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I was looking on VSTS, but I didn't found how to estimate our Tasks/users story in hours instead of Story point.

Is this possible?

I know the pro(and cons) of story points, buf for now our team want to move progressively with agile, and we don't want to start to estimate in story points.

Thank you!

**Edit** as requested, I currently use the agile template(but open to change)

Comment: Judging by the work item types names you use in the question I assume you are using the Agile template. Can you please add the current template you use to the question and if it is customized add which template it is based on.

Answer (score 2):

Declare "One story point is equal to one hour" and use the existing field as-is.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Use the built-in scrum template

---

If you use the built-in Scrum template Tasks have `Remaining Work` and PBI's have `Effort`. Nothing says `Remaing Work = hours` or `Effort = story points`. 
[image]
[image]

If you want to estimate your tasks in number of 4 hour work blocks it will take to complete you can do that, if you want to do it in hours you can do that. Same goes for effort you can put any number in there you want as long as you make sure everyone in your team understands what 1 or 5 or 10 means.

So if possible switch to the scrum template, your question is exactly the reason why these fields have a more generic name than `Story Points` or `Remaining Hours` in the scrum template. Added bonus is that your team can switch definition if they feel like some other number or unit suits your estimation process better.

This blog post makes a good comparison between the built-in different templates:
https://nkdagility.com/choosing-a-process-template-for-your-team-project/

Answer (score 0):

If you are an administrator in VSTS select the VSTS button at the top left of the screen. Then select then select the cog.
[image]

This will take you to a page where you can edit a number of settings. Select `Process`. 
[image]
In the process window choose the process your project uses. You can see which one your project is using by the numbers on the right  hand side of the process. Once you’ve found your process select it by clicking. 
[image]

Then choose the work item type you wish to change. So in this instance `user story`.

Once in the task you want to change select add group and name the group want to add and select it's placement on the card.

[image]

[image]

When the group has been added select it and choose the ellipses (`...`). Then select `Add Field`. Customise the field to be either a new one of your choosing or choose a predefined one.

[image]

[image]

Once you have added this step repeat the process on  this page to customise and style the task how you like. Once done navigate back to your project in VSTS and the changes will be applied